# How to erase current bitmap image from ImageView

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, imageview

I have a method that draws a bitmap image and then overlays it on a camera preview. This method redraws the image as the screen changes size to ensure the overlay is always properly positioned. My problem is that I cannot remove the previous bitmap from the ImageView and subsequent bitmaps just get added on top of previous ones. I have debugged to ensure that the bitmaps being drawn do not contain the previous bitmaps, so it seems that one is just getting laid on top of the others. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
    void ViewSizeChangeWatcherSizeChanged(object sender, ViewSizeChangeMonitor.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        HintImageView.SetImageBitmap(null); // does not work
        HintImageView.SetImageDrawable(null); // does not work
        HintImageView.SetImageResource(0); // does not work 
        HintImageView.SetImageResource(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent); // does not work

        var bitmap = Utility.DrawHintForFaceFront(Math.Min(e.Width, e.Height), Color.ParseColor("#64FFFFFF"), Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        HintImageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        HintImageView.BringToFront();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call  `HintImageView.SetImageDrawable(null);` onStop() &

```
var bitmap = Utility.DrawHintForFaceFront(Math.Min(e.Width, e.Height), Color.ParseColor("#64FFFFFF"), Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        HintImageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        HintImageView.BringToFront();
```

call this part of code in onStart()